# C++ dl_iterate_phdr аналог

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Подскажите пожалуйста аналог dl_iterate_phdr не для линукса

Answer (score 0):

Есть функция [EnumProcessModulesEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodulesex)